# displayName returns null when createUserWithEmailAndPassword Firebase React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a small `React app` and I want to make a `Firebase` registration functionality with adding a `username` in registration. Registration is successful, but adding a username does not work, I get `null` in `displayName`.

```
  const createUser = (email, password, username) => {
    updateProfile(auth.currentUser,{
      displayName: username
    })
   return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password,username);
  };
```

Signup page

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError("");
    if (validPass) {
      try {
        await createUser(email, password, username);
        navigate("/account");
        setNoUser(false);
      } catch (e) {
        setError(e.message);
      }
    } else {
      setWrongPassword(true);
    }
  };

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   <div>
   <label>Username</label>
    <input
      onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
      type="text"
      placeholder="place for username"
      required
     />
    </div>
    <div>
     <label>Email Address</label>
     <input
       onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
       type="email"
       placeholder="place for email"
       required
      />
     </div>
  //Here is the rest of the code that works
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of API calls here is wrong:

```
const createUser = (email, password, username) => {
  updateProfile(auth.currentUser,{
    displayName: username
  })
 return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password,username);
};
```

You can only call `updateProfile` once the account has been created, but you call it *before* calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

What you'll want to do is:

```
const createUser = (email, password, username) => async {
  const result = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password,username)
  updateProfile(auth.currentUser,{
    displayName: username
  })
  return result;
};
```

---

Note that the `updateProfile` may not immediately update the data in `currentUser`. So if you want to show the result right away, you'll want to reload the profile after updating it.

```
const createUser = (email, password, username) => async {
  const result = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password,username)
  await updateProfile(auth.currentUser,{
    displayName: username
  })
  await auth.currentUser.reload();
  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `updateProfile()` before having created the user in the Firebase service, therefore it cannot work.

You should first create the user and then update the profile, for example as follows:

```
let user:
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    user = userCredential.user;
    return updateProfile(user,{
      displayName: username
    })
  })
  .then(() => {
    return user;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```